# Aggregate with query bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query that works as expected:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "valueType": {
              "value": "VARIABLE",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "intent": {
              "value": "CREATED",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "value.name": {
              "value": "item",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "recordType": {
              "value": "EVENT",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*\\\"N_POLIZZA\\\"\\:\\\"2264798\\\"*",
            "fields": [
              "value.value"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "_source": true
}
```

Here the mapping:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to aggregate (group by) by processInstanceKey, so I add this after query {}:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupby_processInstanceKey": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "value.processInstanceKey"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "_source": true
}
```

But it does not work, results are still the same, it seems like no aggregation has been done. I'm a newbie and probably miss something.

Comment: The aggregations results come after the hits, did you scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, I still got the same result no aggregation, thanks for the hint by the way I did not know

Comment: Where are you sending this query from? Kibana Dev Tools?

Comment: you right my friend! sorry I was looking in the wrong window, shame on me. Please reply to my question so I can set as answer. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregations results come after the hits, you need to scroll to the bottom in order to see the aggregation results.

If you're not interested in hits, you can also set `"size": 0` so you only get aggregation results.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to paginate the your buckets, you need to use the [`composite` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination) with a `terms` source instead.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 10,
        "sources": [
          { 
             "groupby_processInstanceKey": { 
                "terms": { 
                   "field": "value.processInstanceKey",
                   "order": "asc"
                }
             } 
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: one more thing, is there a way to paginate the aggregation result? I see I can use size but not from.

Comment: I've updated my answer